# Linux Shell - Find Top k Number Of Processes

Tags: linux, shell, command

I am trying to figure out how to get the top k number of processes in a linux shell.  Obviously the first thing that popped into my head is `top`, but it does not seem to have any parameter to specify the number of processes to print.

Using batch mode and number of iterations parameters, I can get it to produce one iteration of all the processes and store the output, but I cannot find a way to abridge the list to a certain number.  (Granted I could just get the whole list and crop it off, but the system I am using it on has 27000 processes running, so it takes a few seconds to retrieve the list).

Example:

```
>top -b -n1
>... (lots more processes here)
>26416 mcm101    20   0  4188  176   96 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 character_count
>26604 root      20   0  180m 5684 3532 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.54 sshd
>26616 pwf7      20   0  105m 1792 1432 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.10 bash
```

What I want is something like this:

```
>top k
>1 mcm101    20   0  4188  176   96 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 character_count
>2 pwf7      20   0  105m 1792 1432 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.10 bash
>... (more processes here)
>k root      20   0  180m 5684 3532 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.54 sshd
```

Does anyone know how to use `top` or any other command(s) to achieve this result?

Comment: How do you rank your `k` processes ?

Comment: By the %CPU field of the top command (which i believe is the default).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
top -b -n1 | grep '^ *[0-9]' | head -n $k
```

`top` will output all processes in order of CPU usage, `grep` will select those lines from the output that start with a number (i.e. those that start with a PID) and `head` will output the first `k` lines from that output.

Comment: Perfect!  I know thats kind of simple but I'm relatively new to linux commands so it seemed quite difficult! :D